# Google reCaptchav2 error required parameters: site key

Tags: jquery, single-page-application, recaptcha

I recently started a webpage with the posibilty for clients to send mail to my account, sadly i forgot to place a CAPTCHA and it got flooded by bots in no time. I started looking at the Google docs for reCaptcha but i have come to a halt with this error.

My page is loaded dynamically with jQuery and so I need an explicit render, I followed the steps given by Google but the error: `Uncaught Error: Missing required parameters: sitekey` keeps appearing and no captcha renders.

This is my form:

```
<form id="mailForm"  >
        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required> <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>

        <textarea id="message" rows="10" cols="50" name="message" placeholder="Your message" required></textarea>

         <div id="recaptcha"></div>

        <input type="submit" id="mailButt" onclick="mailSend()" value="Send">

    </form>
```

The function used to call the render (MY_SITEKEY is replaced by my sitekey in the original code)

```
function loadCaptcha()
    {    
      grecaptcha.render($('#recaptcha'), {
          'sitekey' : 'MY_SITEKEY'
        });
    };
```

Which is called when the ajax which loads the page is successful

```
loadCaptcha();
```

and finally the script provided by Google, this has been placed at the end of the `<body>` and just before `</head>` with both options still not fixng the error:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit" async defer>
</script>
```

I have tried many configurations of the code but it wont render the captcha box no matter what

Answer (score 0):

You forget to pass the function by loading the script : onload=loadCaptcha

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=loadCaptcha&render=explicit"
        async defer>
```

I know syntax is the same, but try to change the function like in the documention : Explicit rendering after an onload callback

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var onloadCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
      'sitekey' : 'your_site_key'
    });
  };
</script>
```

Documentation here : https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Explicit render after an onload callback</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
          'sitekey' : 'your_site_key'
        });
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div id="html_element"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried that and the result is the same. If the error is something else it is confusing that it states that it can't find the sitekey. Thanks anyway

Comment: An error on the input (not a response of the problem) : use <input type="submit" id="mailButt" value="Send"> (form will be submit) or <input type="button" id="mailButt" onclick="mailSend()" value="Send">

Comment: I added that because the function `mailSend()` avoids the form to reload the page, but thankyou, it would be an error otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to happen whenever a DOM element is passed to the render() function.

If the element's id is passed as a string instead, it should go away.